# Why does my XLS repeat xls:value-of instead taking the next information?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working at my first XML-Project. As an example I took a mobile agent with customers. I have a problem at my XSLT sheet. I try to get all customers in a table with their informations. Till country as you can see in the code, everything works fine. In contract he tooks the first informations and add the to the second, third and foruth customers. Maybe someone can help me out? Here you have the code from xml and xslt.
XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html.xsl"?>              
<Vodafone>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10000">
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <LastName>Meier</LastName>
        <FirstName>Olaf</FirstName>
        <Username>Oleier</Username>
        <Password>Oleier123</Password>
        <Email>Olaf@meier.com</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0511 654321</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>21</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2017</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>21</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2019</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="1234 5678 9012 3457" SecurityCode="260">
                <Brand>Visa</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>08</Month>
                    <Year>2022</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0173 7654321</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young XL</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10002">
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <LastName>Harman</LastName>
        <FirstName>Agathe</FirstName>
        <Username>Agathe1337</Username>
        <Password>hArAtHe77</Password>
        <Email>Agathe@gmx.de</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0511 123456</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>01</Day>
                <Month>02</Month>
                <Year>2017</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>01</Day>
                <Month>02</Month>
                <Year>2019</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="4321 8765 4321 8795" SecurityCode="062">
                <Brand>MasterCard</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>02</Month>
                    <Year>2022</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0173 1234567</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young L</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10002">
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <LastName>Müller</LastName>
        <FirstName>Detlef</FirstName>
        <Username>Detti88</Username>
        <Password>password123</Password>
        <Email>Detlef@web.de</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0511 687642</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>15</Day>
                <Month>05</Month>
                <Year>2016</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>15</Day>
                <Month>05</Month>
                <Year>2018</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="2431 5942 6482 1379" SecurityCode="555">
                <Brand>AmericanExpress</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>05</Month>
                    <Year>2025</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0172 7641359</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young M</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Customer_ID="10002">
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <LastName>Basel</LastName>
        <FirstName>Annabelle</FirstName>
        <Username>Ansel89</Username>
        <Password>safetyfirst5</Password>
        <Email>basel@strato.de</Email>
        <PhoneNumber>0511 555987</PhoneNumber>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
        <Contract>
            <Contracted> 
                <Day>27</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2017</Year>
            </Contracted>
            <Expiration> 
                <Day>27</Day>
                <Month>12</Month>
                <Year>2019</Year>
            </Expiration>
            <CreditCard CardNumber="1111 2222 3333 4444" SecurityCode="123">
                <Brand>MasterCard</Brand>
                <Expiration>
                    <Month>12</Month>
                    <Year>2020</Year>
                </Expiration>
            </CreditCard>
            <MobilePhoneNumber>0173 7775556</MobilePhoneNumber>
            <Tariff>Young S</Tariff>
        </Contract>
    </Customer>
</Vodafone>
```

XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Vodafone Customers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Vodafone Customer:</h1>
    <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phonenumber</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Contracted</th>
                    <th>Expiration</th>
                    <th>Creditcard</th>
                </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Vodafone/Customer">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Gender"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Username"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Password"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Email"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="PhoneNumber"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Country"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="//Contract/Contracted"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="//Contract/Expiration"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="//Contract/CreditCard/Brand"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double-slash `//` from these lines

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="//Contract/Contracted"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="//Contract/Expiration"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="//Contract/CreditCard/Brand"/></td>
```

because they select all the `Contract` elements from the whole document (from which you always get the first element) instead of just the current `Contract`. Also, to make sure that if the different value nodes are not concatenated automatically, put them all in a `concat` function.

It should look like this:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="concat(Contract/Contracted/Day, '/', Contract/Contracted/Month,'/',Contract/Contracted/Year)"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="concat(Contract/Expiration/Day, '/', Contract/Expiration/Month,'/',Contract/Expiration/Year)"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Contract/CreditCard/Brand"/></td>
```

Comment: when i remove t he double-slash, nothing appears in the table.

Comment: @sharete: I changed my answer to address a possible error.

Comment: maybe you can help me at one more thing. which command do i have to use, when i want to take the attribute cardnumber also into the table?

Comment: Glad I could help. For cardnumber use this expression: `Contract/CreditCard/@CardNumber`.

Comment: I don't want to steal you time but I got one more complicated question. Is it possible, to create a line which contains that when the contract expires in 6 month, the customer is able to choose a new smartphone? Like in the table is a header with "New smartphone" and when the contract expires < 6 month new smartphone = yes else = no?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but that's a whole different question which is not well answerable in the comments.